# How to make a function L with lambda that return true if if x is in the set L

Tags: python, lambda, contains

I'm trying to write a function using `lambda` and assign it to a variable, L for example. It should return `true` if passed argument `x` is contained in the set `L`:

L = { (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)} # example
x = (2, 3, 5) #example

```
L = lambda x : list.__contains__(L, x)
```

doesn't seem to work.
The idea is i want to use L as a variable and as a function as the same time.

*Where I'm wrong? What is the best way to achieve this?*

Comment: Post your list or tuple data as well

Comment: you want to create e function L that refer him self? or L already exists and you are trying to override it?

Comment: Why not do `lambda_func = lambda x: x in mylist`? Anyway, maybe you are passing strings vs ints or something like that? Give your L and x values. Also what @Scantlight said, you are reassigning L which seems to be the initial list. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Is **L** a `list` or a `function`?

Comment: Yes. At first L is a set. I want to make a function that is called L also and that return true if x is in L .

Answer (score 0):

Use `in`:

```
func = lambda elem, cont: elem in cont

li = [1, 2, 3]
print(func(1, li))
>> True
print(func(4, li))
>> False
```

But for this kind of usage a normal `def` syntax can be used for sake of simplicity.

Comment: Thank you and if i want that the func had the same name as cont what i an do?

Comment: In this case you can, but I don't see any reason you would want to.

Answer (score 0):

From PEP-8:
"Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier."

Why do not use:

```
def check(obj, iterable):
    return True if obj in iterable else False
```

?

Answer (score 0):

When you define a `lambda` function, it will assigned to `L` variable *without being executed*, so the original content of `L` will be lost before using it and will refer a `function` but not to a `set`.

If you will try:

```
L = { (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)}
L = lambda x: x in L
L((1, 2, 3))
```

you will get an error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable
```

As you can see, at the moment when using `L`, it will be of `type function` and not a `set` anymore. So *this is a wrong approach*, unless you are thinking to use more that one context.

To do it in the right way, you should have one variable which links to your data set and another for your function (lambda).

```Python
L = {(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)}
F = lambda x: x in L
if F((1, 2, 3)):
    print("was found in L")
```